# What is wrong with using :label for SQL UPDATE statement?

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I have the following sql code:

```
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare('UPDATE Album
SET title = :title, date_created = :date_created, date_modified = :date_modified,
  location = :location, creator = :creator
WHERE id = :id;')
```

which returns error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ':title, date_created = :date_created, date_modified =
>   :date_modified,
>         loca' at line 2

Why am I getting this error? Is ":label" not a valid thing to do w/ update statements?

### Update

I simplified my code for this post but my real code is:

```
$queryFor = array(
 'Album' => 'UPDATE Album
    SET title = :title, date_created = :date_created, date_modified = :date_modified,
      location = :location, creator = :creator
    WHERE id = :id;',
  'Image' => 'UPDATE Image
    SET title = :title, date_created = :date_created, caption = :caption, credit = :credit
    WHERE id = :id;');

$sqlFieldsFor = array(
  'Album' => array('title', 'date_created', 'date_modified', 'location', 'creator'),
  'Image' => array('title', 'date_created', 'caption', 'credit'));

//Get info
$error['error'] = '';
//$requestType = 'Album'
$requestType = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'requestType', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
  if (empty($requestType)) {
    $error['error'] = 'Missing requestType';

    die();
  }
//$id = 2
$id = intval($db->real_escape_string($_POST["id"]));

//Execute sql
$stmt = $db->prepare($queryFor[$requestType]); //returns false :(
$error['statement'] = $db->error;
foreach ($sqlFieldsFor[$requestType] as $field) {
  $value = $_POST[$field];
  $parameter = ":$field";
  $stmt->bindValue($parameter, $value);
}
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$executed = $stmt->execute();
if(!$executed){
  $error['error'] = "SQL query $queryFor[$requestType] not executed";
  echo json_encode($error);
  exit();
}
```

Comment: I assume you are executing with an associative array. The syntax is appropriate for a prepared statement, and I can’t see any particular error.

Comment: @Manngo yes I've posted my real code in the update. For some reason it works if I use `?` instead of `:label`. Do you know why that is?

Comment: Can you show your execute statement (and any bind statements)?

Comment: @Manngo I updated my post to have my code (unsimplified b/c I use a lot of arrays)

Comment: I’ll have a look at this, but I’ll add this comment: if you’re using prepared statements, which is a good thing, you no longer need to use `real_escape_string`. That is especially the case if you’re running data through `intval`, since any potential SQL injection is wiped out with the rest of the non-integer data. You _do_ need to check whether `$_POST` is properly populated, but in your case, you can do this with a simple `intval(@$_POST['id'])` which will result in a simple integer or 0.

Comment: OK, how is `requestType` coming in? I suggest that your array use lower case keys, so you can then use `strtolower` on your input (or ditto with upper case). That way you avoid the risk of a type sensitivity probelem.

Comment: @Manngo thank you for your help. I decided to switch from `mysqli` to `pdo` and now I don't get an error but the database is not updating...but that's another issue. Thank  you for your help!

Comment: I was going to recommend using PDO on this one. I find it _much_ easier!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to switch from `mysqli` to`pdo` and execute a prepared statement with an array of insert values (named parameters)

```
$stmt = $db->prepare($queryFor[$requestType]);
$paramToValues = array();
foreach ($sqlFieldsFor[$requestType] as $field) {
  $value = $_POST[$field];
  $parameter = ":$field";
  $paramToValues[$parameter] = $value;
}
$executed = $stmt->execute($paramToValues);
```

A good example of what I did (b/c my code is a bit confusing) is in the [php pdo documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php):

```
<?php
/* Execute a prepared statement by passing an array of insert values */
$calories = 150;
$colour = 'red';
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT name, colour, calories
    FROM fruit
    WHERE calories < :calories AND colour = :colour');
$sth->execute(array(':calories' => $calories, ':colour' => $colour));
?>
```

Now I'm running into other issues but at least I don't have a sql syntax error!